# AJAX + Rails: Should I Use a GET or a PUT When Creating a Route?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My question: When using AJAX within Rails, from a best practice standpoint, does the HTML verb that I use (e.g., `get`) to define a route matter? Is it OK to basically always use `get`?

Context: In my Rails App, I've built the following:

- When a user selects an HTML checkbox, that triggers a JQuery listener that lives in a file inside of `/app/assets/javascripts`.
- This `.js` file makes an AJAX call to a controller/action: `foos#bar`. My JS passes an ID into the action.
- To route this request, I've added the following to `routes.rb`: `get "/foos/bar" => "foos#bar"`. This tells my App which controller/action should process the AJAX call.
- The controller/action handles this request just fine. The action grabs the ID as a URL parameter, updates the relevant model object, and finally returns back a `200` to the JS AJAX caller.

This all works great! No issues -- nothing to troubleshoot here.

My question is: In the example above, is it appropriate to define a `get` route within `routes.rb` to process this AJAX request? Or, is that bad practice? Should I instead be defining a `put`, since conceptually that is what I'm doing in this workflow (i.e., I'm updating an existing object)? I'm worried that, while this all works perfectly, I'm breaking some fundamental MVC routing standards.

Answer (score 2):

If you are updating a resource it will most likely be a `PATCH` update, which means you aren't completely replacing the resource but are just updating it (this is why `PATCH` is the default HTTP method for updates in Rails, instead of `PUT`).

So, yes, you are violating RESTful conventions by using `GET` to update a resource. `GET` is only used to fetch a representation of a resource...without changing it in any way.